# Minecraft Mouse sensitivity is sluggish

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My problem is that whenever I join minecraft my mouse sensitivity is really sluggish and the mouse setting won't work for me. That setting is on 90% and my mouse still acts weird. Someone please help me.

Comment: is your mouse this slow outside of Minecraft? if not, then you probably have a problem with the game or mouse, otherwise, find your mouse settings (varies by OS) and change the overall sensitivity. you may also want to try cleaning the sensor on the bottom, dust and grime can mess it up.

Comment: It should be noted that, for the sensitivity option, 100% is default, so 90% is below the normal mouse speed. Also, the sensitivity option is only for looking around; your normal mouse speed should be used on GUIs. Is your mouse slow outside of Minecraft? Is it slow turning your camera around, or when on inventories and menus? What do you mean by "acts weird"?

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but please try to add more detail to your post so we can help you out :)

Comment: By chance, do you also notice your camera still moving even though you've stopped moving your mouse?  It might be Camera sliding enabled, and hitting F8 should give you 1:1 control again.  Besides that, is this experienced in any other game?

Answer (score 0):

If your mouse is slow in real life, then really you should go to settings and do sensitivity, and if that does not work, try cleaning the bottom of the mouse, get a mousepad, and/or get a new mouse :D hope this works.